# Class extends and use properties inside static property as itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been struggling with generics on TypeScript for a while now, I got the following setup

The following generic class:

```js
class Entity {  
    public static schema = {};
}
```

And the class that extends it:

```js
class User extends Entity {
    public static schema = {
       username: ""
    }
}
```

If I instantiate the class, I want to use its parameters like

```js
let user = new User();
user.username = "John Doe" //does not work
```

I've tried using parameters and a generic type like:

```js
type EntityType<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: T[k];
};
```

but in no way I could get it working, even using index signatures with interfaces and type, but I was getting a lot of syntax errors and didn't know how to work around it.

Any ideas if I can do that or something like it?

Comment: I don't really get the point of the static schema here; surely `class User extends Entity { username = "" }` is the way to give `User` instances a property named `username`.  If you need something different it would really help to see a [mre] that motivates using static properties.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to access your `username` static property is wrong.
It yields in another declaration space.
Beside that you mislead about `schema` object where `username` is defined.

You should access it from class itself

```
User.schema.username
```

Or from constructor of an instance

```
let user = new User()
user.constructor.schema.username
```

Note that constructor is common for every instance of User class so as are its static properties.
Thus every user have one indifferent name in your example.